# Overriding Template in Shopware 4 from plugin

Tags: templates, shopware

```
public function install() {
    $this->subscribeEvent(
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend',
        'onFrontendPostDispatch',
        0
    );

    return array('success' => true, 'invalidateCache' => array('frontend'));
}

public function onFrontendPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
    $controller = $args->get('subject');
    $view = $controller->View();

    $view->addTemplateDir(
        __DIR__ . '/Views'
    );
}
```

I had tried to run the plugin and override Template but Shopware does not see changes in a plugin.

I am creating new file in `/Views/frontend/checkout/cart_footer.tpl` in plugins root.

I am also insert

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/checkout/cart_footer.tpl'}
```

line in .tpl file but still no success.

Does any one know where is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very easy

I just add one line

```
$view->loadTemplate('frontend/plugins/checkout/cart.tpl');
```

And change code little bit.

I am change event from **`Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend`** to 
   **`Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_Checkout`**

and add **`$view->loadTemplate('frontend/plugins/checkout/cart.tpl');`**
This path is related from **`"/Views"`** folder which is declared in **`addTemplateDir`** method.

Bellow is whole code, Enjoy :)

```
public function install() {
    $this->subscribeEvent(
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_Checkout',
        'onFrontendPostDispatch'
    );

    return array('success' => true, 'invalidateCache' => array('frontend'));
}


public function onFrontendPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
    $controller = $args->get('subject');
    $view = $controller->View();

    $view->addTemplateDir(
        __DIR__ . '/Views'
    );

    $view->loadTemplate('frontend/plugins/checkout/cart.tpl');
}
```